# Hausdorff, continuous and one-to-one function

Tags: general-topology

Suppose  and  are topological spaces and :  →  is continuous and one – to – one. Prove if  is Hausdorff then  must be Hausdorff. Also give example show that that X is not a Hausdorff if one-to-one condition is dropped.

I can prove that X is a Hausdorff if f is continuous and one-to-one. But I can not give an example that X is not a Hausdorff if one-to-one condition is dropped.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take $X$ to be any non-Hausdorff space (e.g., an indiscrete space with more than $1$ point), take $Y$ to be the space with just one point and take $f$ to be the unique mapping from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Can you please explain more? As I know that discrete topology on any set is Hausdorff space. Thanks

Comment: Apologies: "discrete" was a typo that I have just corrected. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

take $x_1, x_2 \in X,$ then take $f(x_1) \in U, f(x_2) \in V$ with $U,V$ disjoint in $Y$ by Hausdorff. Now take the inverse images of $U$ and $V.$

Comment: This is proof X is a Hausdorff. But if one-to-one is dropped then need to give an example that is X is not Hausdorff. I need that example. Thanks